# Show Daily Archives after specific dates

Tags: archives

I am currently showing a daily archive using the following

```
 <?php wp_get_archives('type=daily&limit=15'); ?>
```

It shows all the older posts as daily archives. However, Is it possible to show the archives only after a specific dates. For instance, I would like to show daily archives from August 1, 2013 onward only and not any post which was published before that.

I have tried to use the following code but somehow does not work

```
<?php
function ($where) { return $where . ' AND  (post_date)>= 2013-08-01 '; }
add_filter('getarchives_where');
?>
<ul>       
<?php wp_get_archives('type=daily'); ?>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: you can use `getarchives_where` filter to filter your `wp_get_archives();` query

Answer (score 1):

do so like this

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'my_archives_filter_function', 10, 2 );
```

create function

```
function my_archives_filter_function($text, $r) {
     return "WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_date >= '2013-08-01'";
}
```

Comment: EDIT: post date >= 2013-08-01

Comment: no problem, accept answer by clicking on tick icon to mark as solved.